# adding array elements to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a very big list which is an array named `leagues`, I need to allow the user to take the elements on that array(list) , and choose those as favorites by clicking a button

```
$scope.favoriteLeagues = [];

$scope.favoriteLeague = function(league) {

  $scope.favoriteLeagues.push(league);

}
```

so I want to know what am I doing wrong ? the function sometimes allows me to add one as favorite, but once I click on the second one, I got a message of something undefined, and also, the binding is not working, I am unable to see the `{{favoriteLeagues.name}}` printed.

**UPDATED AS REQUESTED**

```
<div>
      <strong>Favorites</strong>
        {{favoriteLeagues.name}}
    </div>
    <ion-option-button class="button-light icon ion-star"
                       on-tap="favoriteLeague(league)">
    </ion-option-button>
    <div ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter = (sports | filter:query)">
            <strong>{{sport.name}}</strong>
     </div>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues">
            <div>{{league.name}}</div>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

here the controller:

```
  .controller('SportsController', function($scope, $state,
                                           AuthFactory, SportsFactory) {
    $scope.favoriteLeagues = [];
    $scope.sports = [];

    AuthFactory.getCustomer().then(function(customer) {
      $scope.customer = customer;
      SportsFactory.getSportsWithLeagues(customer).then(function(sports) {
        if (sports.length) {
          $scope.sports = sports;
        }

      $scope.isSportShown = function(sport) {
        return $scope.shownSport === sport;
      };

      $scope.favoriteLeague = function(league) {

        $scope.favoriteLeagues.push(league);

       }

      };

     });
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: sorry, see my update

Comment: You are using the same name for your array and function, you can only have one, you need to rename one of them

Comment: You never iterate over the `favoriteLeague` array - you can't simply call `array.property` without specifying an index.

Comment: @tymeJV see my update now, is printing on the console the array element that the user chooses, but still not doing the binding on ```{{favoriteLeagues.name}}```

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer -- Because `favoriteLeagues` is an array! You need to specify an index!

Comment: Can we have the full HTML context?  Like is this stuff inside an ng-repeat?  How are you displaying the various objects?

Comment: Also you defined $scope.favouriteLeague but are trying to push into $scope.favouriteLeagues - notice the extra 's'

Comment: Can we see your controller code?

Comment: @mindparse go to the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't pasted the full html, but it should look something like this:

```
<!-- Use ng-app to auto-bootstrap an AngularJS application-->
<!-- Use ng-controller to attach your view with your SportsController  controller -->
<ion-list>
    <div>
        <strong>Favorites</strong>
        <!-- Looping through all the favourite leagues-->
        <div ng-repeat="favouriteL in favoriteLeagues">
            {{favouriteL.name}}        
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Looping through all the sports -->            
    <div ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter = (sports | filter:query)"> 
        <!-- Bind the sport name -->            
        <strong>{{sport.name}}</strong>

        <!-- Looping through all the leagues -->                
        <ion-item ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues">
            <!-- Display a button which on tap will call favoriteLeague function -->                
            <ion-option-button class="button-light icon ion-star" on-tap="favoriteLeague(league)">    
            </ion-option-button>
            <!-- Bind the name of the league -->                
            <div>{{league.name}}</div>
        </ion-item>

    </div>
</ion-list>
```

Don't forget to attach the view with your controller using ng-controller.

Answer (score 2):

I can't help you much with angular.js, I've never used it, but the fact that you are accidentally replacing the array with the function probably doesn't help. ng-repeat is trying to loop through favoriteLeagues but fails because that's a function! Look at the comments I put in your code.

```
$scope.favoriteLeague = []; // creates an array

$scope.favoriteLeague = function(league) { // replaces the array with a function!!!

  $scope.favoriteLeagues.push(league); // suddenly leagues takes an S ?

}
```

To avoid this type of error, you should respect a naming convention for your functions. I like to use action words and verbs for functions. I only use plural forms on arrays and related functions. Here's what I'd do in your case:

```
$scope.favoriteLeagues = [];

$scope.addToFavoriteLeagues = function(league) {
  $scope.favoriteLeagues.push(league);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach your controller to the html in order for the bind to work, usually at the top level parent element, e.g a div, containing the ngrepeat markup.

Comment: I have that in the index view bro.