# Javascript: Add array elements to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to split elements in array noted below into 2 separate arrays:
data and labels:

Example using below would look like this:

**data:** [9, 23, 1, 6]
**labels:** ['service-1', 'service-2', 'service-3', 'service-4']

```
    Array[16]
       .    0: Object
           .    data: 9
           .    labels: "service-1"
           .    __proto__: Object
       .    1: Object
           .    data: 23
           .    labels: "service-2"
           .    __proto__: Object
       .    2: Object
           .    data: 1
           .    labels: "service-3"
           .    __proto__: Object
       .    3: Object
           .    data: 6
           .    labels: "service-4"
           .    __proto__: Object
```

I'm trying to keep this simple as possible as I've tried several different things that have not worked including reference in this post: [add array elements to other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28330237/adding-array-elements-to-another-array),

Comment: Can you post the code for what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var dataLabels = [
  {data: 9, label: "service-1"},
  {data: 23, label: "service-2"},
  {data: 1, label: "service-3"},
  {data: 6, label: "service-4"}
];

var data = [];
var labels = [];

dataLabels.forEach(function(element) {
    data.push(element.data);
    labels.push(element.label);
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing this will work as well and thank you for your post.  I haven't retested all of these yet.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your array has a JS object notation, I think this should work:

```
var data = [];
var labels = [];

for (var i= 0;i<16; i++){
    data[i] = array[i].data;
    labels[i] = array[i].labels;
}
```

Comment: Hardcoding `array.length` of 16 is far from optimal.

Comment: I'm torn. On one hand, I think that people take answer on SO and adapt them to best practices that they know or use - and understand that answers on SO are oftentimes like they are for brevity than anything else. On the other hand... *CTRL-C, CTRL-V, done!* **cringe**

Comment: Thanks for responses, but I'm getting undefined returned.

Comment: georgeb1, please notice that I used array[i] in the for loop, but you actually don't have a variable called 'array'- at least in the part you shared. Please share your JS code and the error you get. You can't get useful feedback without showing your code and the error messages explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I understand that @melis.  I substituted the correct array that returns current output above.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick. Although perhaps a loop will suffice.

```
var dataLabels = [
  {
    data: 9,
    labels: "service-1"
  }, {
    data: 23,
    labels: "service-2"
  }
];

var data = dataLabels.map(function(element) {
  return element.data;
});

var labels = dataLabels.map(function(element) {
  return element.labels;
});
```

Comment: In this code, the `dataLabels` are looped through twice.

Comment: True it loops twice but expresses intent better than a `forEach` call.

Comment: Would someone mind providing jsfiddle?.. I appreciate the suggestions, but they aren't working.

Comment: My apologies!  .. This does work.  I was testing something with a different array earlier.  Thank You.

Comment: @jdphenix: the intent is to create two new arrays and to do so most efficiently.  Doubling the run time and doubling code declarations `dataLabels.map` is suboptimal.  You are welcome to take a look at performance results here: http://jsfiddle.net/uws424x9/.  Cheers.

Comment: @DRD - Thank You!  I actually did implement your approach with the forEach loop.